# How to make bluetooth mouse automatically reconnect to my Microsoft Surface 3?

Tags: windows-8, mouse, bluetooth, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a new MS Surface Pro 3 running Win 8.1. At my office I have a Logitech M557 bluetooth mouse and at home an Apple magic mouse. When I come home and wake my surface from sleep it doesn't want to connect to the magic mouse automatically. How can I fix this?

When I open 'Bluetooth' within 'PC and devices' it lists my `Bluetooth Mouse M557` as 'Not connected' and then beneath that lists my magic mouse, with no grey status beneath it. If I click that item I just have the option to `Remove Device`. I've tried switching the mouse off and on to no avail.

If I `Remove device` then switch it off and on again it's listed again with status 'Ready to pair', and I can then select it & click `Pair`, and then it works fine.

But surely I shouldn't have to remove it and reconnect it each time?

Possibly related, I have another problem pertaining to my M557 mouse: if I set the PC and devices > Mouse and Touchpad > Touchpad setting  'Leave touchpad on when a mouse is connected' to OFF, then when I take my Surface somewhere without my M557 mouse and I try to use my touchpad it doesn't work. So it's not recognising that my mouse is no longer connected and therefore isn't re-enabling my touchpad. Instead I have to navigate my way around the UI via the keyboard to switch off this setting. This makes me wonder if the problem with my magic mouse isn't with the connection to that device but that windows isn't recognising that the M557 is no longer connected. Except of course that it shows as 'Not connected' in bluetooth devices list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

1. In the USB Port Power Management settings and Bluetooth Devices settings, disable 'Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power'
2. Open Devices setup > Bluetooth Devices window, and keeping it open in background do your other work.
3. When the mouse freezes, use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to go to Bluetooth Devices window & move the mouse, it unfreezes.
4. Continue with your other work... always use Bluetooth Devices window to unfreeze mouse

Comment: How do I get to #1?

Comment: I got to the #1 by going to Control Panel > Device Manager > Bluetooth >, then find your bluetooth device and right click > Properties. Under `Power Management`, you will find the option there.